# Do inner and/or partial classes take away from the principle of the State Design Pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, state-pattern

In my ongoing quest to master various design patterns, I ran into the "State" design pattern.

First, let me explain where I am attempting to use this pattern. I have a Form which I would like to apply state to. My program has three states: Configuration, Processing, and ProcessingComplete. When the Form changes state various components of the Form will become enabled/disabled, visible/invisible, etc.

With my understanding of the State pattern, all those changes (making components visible/invisible, enabled/disabled, etc) should occur within a separate class which contains an instance of the Form. If the various State classes are separate from the Form's class, the State classes can not access the Form's components. I feel that this leaves me with one of two options:

1. Expose the Form's components as public
2. Make the State classes a inner class of the Form

I feel that option (1) is bad form, but I feel that option (2) violates the spirit of the State pattern somehow. The other thought I had was use option (2) but using partial class implementations, however I still feel that its violating the spirit of the State pattern.

Are my feelings on either choice unjust, or is there another option I haven't even thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a third option.

> Include the parts the State will control as part of the contract of the class.

So if your goal is to modify the text of a label, your base State class should require a label be sent to it.  Then you can have an `InitializeState(State myState)` or `BuildStates()` method on your form that sets the appropriate fields.

Option 1 is wrong.  Option 2 really becomes unnecessary when you design your State such that it can only act what it is given, which is really how objects should act anyway.

Comment: I really like this idea. I didn't occur to me because I am used to trying to keep my classes fairly immutable, which would mean I would have to implement a probably fairly complex constructor (complex meaning a lot of parameters in this case).

Comment: Thinking further though: "Option 2 really becomes unnecessary when you design your State such that it can only act what it is given". In option 2, the State class must be given an instance of the Form. The advantage being that the State can access the private members of the Form's instance because the State class is nested.

Comment: @Shynthriir:  I don't really consider one class accessing the private members of another an advantage; it's tightly-coupled code.  Even if nested, they should only access what they are given not what they can see.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid partial implementations. Usually hey don't give any added value, and make the code harder to read. The only place I can think of where partial classes are a good idea is when part of your code is auto-generated (like in the WinForms designer).

What about using MVP or some kind of binding? If you bind the Visible and Enabled properties of your controls to a Model class, then you can hold an instance of that Model instead of holding an instance of a form.

Comment: Firstly, the way I see partial implementations is purely to help separate logical portions of your code into separate files. Keeps the files from getting to large, if that's your cup of tea. -- Secondly I'm still wrapping my head around various aspects of MVP.

Comment: @Shynthriir This is dealing with a symptom instead of coping with the problem. If your class is so large that you want to divide it into separate files, then you should divide it into separate CLASSES. Large classes are untestable.

Comment: True. Classes should only have one responsibility, they shouldn't be logically separable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for option 2. The "State" is used for the "Form" only, so it is semantically intrinsic to it, so why not make it that in the class-hierarchy?

Comment: I agree...why can't you use inheritance. That's what OOP was designed for.